# Having issues with my PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a custom PHP class that I build from scratch, it is designed to connect, run a prepared query, output and disconnect from a database.

The issue is that I have had to fight multiple errors.

This being the latest one after the others were fixed.

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php on line 23 Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=8404 in E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php on line 23 Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php:23 Stack trace: #0 E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php(23): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'password') #1 E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php(53): simpleDB->connectToDB() #2 {main} thrown in E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php on line 23 Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\UniServerZ\www\simple db\index.php on line 23

I cannot figure it out though, my login details, host details, etc, etc are all correct, so I am unsure what to do now, I did read some articles online but they weren't much help, so here I am.

Here is my class and connection code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class fooBarBaz {
    protected $conn;
    private $host;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $driver;

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $db, $user, $pass) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    }

    public function connecterino() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->driver . ':host=' . $this->host .';dbname=' . $this->db . ';charset=utf8', $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function queryForStuff($preparedQuery, $params) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($preparedQuery);
            $exec = $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function getResultOfThatStuff($sql) {
        $data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($data as $row){
            print_r($row);
        }
    }

    public function disconnectDB() {
        $this->conn = null;
    }
}

try {
    $db = new fooBarBaz("mysql", "localhost:8000", "myDatabase", "root", "root");
    $db->connecterino();
    $query = $db->queryForStuff("select id from songs where id != :1", [":1" => "2"]);
    $db->getResultOfThatStuff($query);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

How can I get this code working fully as expected?

What have I done wrong/am I blind to?

Thanks.

Comment: General things you should add to a question like this: a) Operating system seems to be windows ....version and 32/64bit?  b) Can you connect with another frontend to this MySQL server (e.g. [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) or the [command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html))? c) Which versions of MySQL / PHP do you use? d) Can you connect to the MySQL server when using straightforward code like `<?php $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly'); ?>` ?

Comment: Specific to your question: `localhost:8000` <- sure? Really, really sure? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK wow., please don't hate me, it is 4am afterall xD! Now it returns data.

Comment: no problem, 5:23am here ;-)

Comment: haha, thanks anyway bud!

Comment: ....but I'm curious: Do you really run the MySQL server on that port or was _that_ the actual error?

Comment: I have had issues with my localhost so changed it over to :8000 to access my "www" folder, so I assumed that since the sites were there, I would have to access SQL on that port too.

Comment: I'm still confused how I moved localhost to run on :8000 but sql isn't there (as your fix showed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect to a port other than the default port your [DSN](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) has to look like

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=8000;dbname=test;charset=utf8
```

instead of

<strike>mysql:host=localhost:8000dbname=test;charset=utf8</strike>